# Can't connect bluetooth audio device to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, audio, android, bluetooth

I recently bought a wireless bluetooth earphones (Awei A960BL). I am able to connect and play audio with it through my Android phone but here come's the problem:

I can't connect or even find it in bluetooth scans using my Linux machine (Ubuntu Gnome 16.04). I also tried searching it in Windows 10 (I'm on dual boot) but still not found on the searches.

What could be the problem? Is there a way to connect my bluetooth device?

P.S. I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with the device since I was able to use it on mobile.

Comment: Does the machine you run Windows/Linux on actually have a Bluetooth connector/dongle/chip?

Comment: @Seth yes, I was able to scan and connect to other bluetooth devices as well (excluding my wireless audio device).